# How to debug slow virtualenv on osx?

Tags: python, macos

For some reason, virtualenvs on my OS X machine have become incredibly slow.

Without virtualenv:

```
$ /usr/bin/time python -c ''
        0.02 real         0.01 user         0.00 sys
```

With virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv myvenv
New python executable in myvenv/bin/python
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
(myenv)$ /usr/bin/time python -c ''
       11.01 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
```

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this.

I'm on OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite) running Python 2.7.6 (system Python).

Comment: First try `python -vvv` and it will print out all the things it imports on startup

Comment: Further makes sure Python versions of virtualenv and non-virtualenv are the same and you are not mixing homebrew Python with system Python

Comment: And further further, use `dtruss` to see what system calls different Pythons make and compare https://opensourcehacker.com/2011/12/02/osx-strace-equivalent-dtruss-seeing-inside-applications-what-they-do-and-why-they-hang/